# remove spaces and lower case all items in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
listx = ['Day Mover ', 'Resurg Micro']
```

Is there a way to make all words lower case and remove all spaces in general code?
I tried:

```
new_list = [elem for elem in listx if elem.strip()]
```

Expected output:

```
new_list = ['day_mover', 'resurg_micro']
```

Comment: `new_list = [elem.strip().lower().replace(" ", "_") for elem in listx]`

Comment: @Rakesh - seems not dupe, reopen?

Comment: @jezrael..its anyway a dupe of multiple questions